# Operator overloading Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, operator-keyword

I'm new to kotlin and I'm working on operators overloading for a custom class I defined. The class is called "Rational" and represents a rational number, like for example 117/1098. Class is defined as below and I have overloaded a bunch of operators, like plus, minus, times and so on. However I'm uncertain about what I have to do to overload "in" operator.

Here is my class:

```kotlin
data class Rational(val rational: String) {
    private val numerator: BigInteger
    private val denominator: BigInteger

    init {
        val splitted = rational.split("/")
        numerator = splitted[0].toBigInteger()
        denominator = when (splitted[1]) {
            "0" -> throw Exception("not allowed")
            else -> splitted[1].toBigInteger()
        }
    }

    operator fun plus(number: Rational): Rational {
        val gcm = denominator * number.denominator
        val numerator = (gcm / denominator) * numerator + (gcm / number.denominator) * number.numerator
        return Rational("$numerator/$gcm")
    }

    operator fun minus(number: Rational): Rational {
        val gcm = denominator * number.denominator
        val numerator = (gcm / denominator) * numerator - (gcm / number.denominator) * number.numerator
        return Rational("$numerator/$gcm")
    }

    operator fun times(number: Rational): Rational {
        val numerator = numerator * number.numerator
        val denominator = denominator * number.denominator
        return Rational("$numerator/$denominator")
    }

    operator fun div(number: Rational): Rational {
        val numerator = numerator * number.denominator
        val denominator = denominator * number.numerator
        return Rational("$numerator/$denominator")
    }

    operator fun compareTo(number: Rational): Int {
        val ratio = this.numerator.toFloat() / this.denominator.toFloat()
        val numberRatio = number.numerator.toFloat() / number.denominator.toFloat()
        if (ratio > numberRatio) {
            return 1
        } else if (ratio == numberRatio) {
            return 0
        }
        return -1
    }

    operator fun unaryMinus(): Rational {
        val inverseNumerator = -numerator
        return Rational("$inverseNumerator/$denominator")
    }

    operator fun unaryPlus(): Rational {
        return Rational("$numerator/$denominator")
    }

    operator fun rangeTo(end: Rational): Any {
        var range: MutableList<Rational> = arrayListOf()
        val startNumerator = this.numerator.toInt()
        val endNumerator = end.numerator.toInt()
        var index = 0
        if (this.denominator == end.denominator) {
            for (i in startNumerator..endNumerator) {
                range.add(index, Rational("$i/$denominator"))
            }
        }
        return range
    }

    operator fun contains(number: Rational): Boolean {
        if (this.denominator % number.denominator == 0.toBigInteger()
                && this.numerator <= number.numerator) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        val gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator)
        return if (gcd != null) {
            val newNumerator = numerator / gcd
            val newDenominator = denominator / gcd
            "$newNumerator/$newDenominator"
        } else {
            "$numerator/$denominator"
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
infix fun Int.divBy(denominator: Int): Rational {
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw Exception("denominator 0 not allowed")
    }

    return Rational("$this/$denominator")
}

infix fun Long.divBy(denominator: Long): Rational {
    if (denominator == 0L) {
        throw Exception("denominator 0 not allowed")
    }
    return Rational("$this/$denominator")
}

infix fun BigInteger.divBy(denominator: BigInteger): Rational {
    if (denominator == 0.toBigInteger()) {
        throw Exception("denominator 0 not allowed")
    }
    return Rational("$this/$denominator")
}

fun String.toRational(): Rational {
    return Rational(this)
}
```

And here is my main body that obviously still doesn't compile:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val half = 1 divBy 2
    val third = 1 divBy 3
    val twoThirds = 2 divBy 3

    println(half in third..twoThirds) // this line does not compile beacause in operator is not defined for the class
}
```

I guess I have to override "rangeTo" operator but I'm uncertain about the operator prototype. I there somebody that can please help me to get to the right track?

Comment: As a matter of design, I'd suggest adding a constructor that takes a pair of `BigInteger`s.  You can then do the GCD calculation there, instead of in `toString()`.  Avoiding all the conversion of `BigInteger`s to `Strings`s and back again should save memory and time, as well as simplifying the code a bit.  You'll probably also want to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, along with operators `inc()`, and `dec()`.  If you override `toByte()` &c, you can implement `Number` too.  And why define `compareTo()` without implementing `Comparable`? — Yes, I've implemented a `Rational` class too :-)

Comment: This looks exactly like the Week 4 assignment for the Coursera course "Kotlin for Java Developers".  I wish I hadn't found it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to make `in` work is for the `third..twoThirds` call to return *something* that has a `contains(Rational)` method, which is what the `in` call translates to.

One way to do this is to return a `ClosedRange<Rational>` here, like so:

```
operator fun rangeTo(end: Rational): ClosedRange<Rational> {
    return object : ClosedRange<Rational> {
        override val endInclusive: Rational = end
        override val start: Rational = this@Rational
    }
}
```

This puts a type constraint on `Rational`, as a [`ClosedRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-closed-range/index.html) needs a [`Comparable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/index.html) implementation to be able to determine whether a value belongs in it. You can do this by implementing the `Comparable` interface, and then adding `operator` to your existing [`compareTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/compare-to.html) operator (plus it's a good practice to rename the parameter to match the interface):

```
data class Rational(val rational: String) : Comparable<Rational> {

    ...

    override operator fun compareTo(other: Rational): Int {
        val ratio = this.numerator.toFloat() / this.denominator.toFloat()
        val numberRatio = other.numerator.toFloat() / other.denominator.toFloat()
        if (ratio > numberRatio) {
            return 1
        } else if (ratio == numberRatio) {
            return 0
        }
        return -1
    }

}
```

You could also avoid the conversion to floats entirely by using this implementation instead, as suggested in the comment below by @gidds:

```
override operator fun compareTo(other: Rational): Int {
    return (numerator * other.denominator - denominator * other.numerator).signum()
}
```

Also, your current `contains` implementation could *probably* be discarded, as you no longer need it, and it functions rather oddly.

---

To add something other than the direct answer here: as @Eugene Petrenko suggested in their answer, it would be practical to add a couple constructors other than the one that uses a `String`, for example one that takes two `Int`s, and one that takes two `BigIntegers`s.

Comment: `compareTo()` doesn't need to do any division or conversions at all: you could just do e.g. `(numerator * other.denominator - denominator * other.numerator).sign`.

Comment: Oops, of course! I'll add this to the answer itself as well, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for all your help :) everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator is declared inverse. You need an extension function on the right side that takes the left side.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#in

You miss an infix function `divBy` to allow turing `Int` into `Rational`, e.g.

```
infix fun Int.divBy(i: Int) = Rational("$this/$i")
```

Not the code like `val half = 1 divBy 2` will work. Theoretically, it may make sense to add a constructor for `Rational` from `Int`s to avoid parsing.

There is an incorrect return type in `rangeTo` method in the `Rational` class, it should not be `Any`. It should be declared as

```
data class RationalRange(val left: Rational, val right: Rational) {
  operator fun contains(r: Rational) = left <= r && r <= right
}

operator fun rangeTo(end: Rational): RationalRange(this, end)
```

Now the example with `x in a..b` should work.

UPD: added the RationalRange. I missed the point, sorry. You do not need `contains` function implemented for the `Rational` class at all.

The `compareTo` function of `Rational` is unlikely to use `.toFloat()` instead, you may implement that directly with integer numbers

Comment: `rangeTo` should most definitely not return a `Rational`, it makes no sense to then check if a `Rational` contains another.

Comment: @Eugene, thanks a lot. Makes more sense know. I have indeed defined infix functions but I forgot to cut & paste them, going  to update the question

Comment: Thanks for all your help :) everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution is to implement the Comparable Interface in your class.

`data class Rational(val rational: String) : Comparable<Rational>`

Then implement the compareTo() function, with your comparison logic.

```
override fun compareTo(other: Rational): Int {
    //Normalize the numerators of each rational
    val thisNumerator = this.numerator * other.denominator
    val otherNumerator = other.numerator * this.denominator
    //Then compare them
    return when{
        thisNumerator > otherNumerator -> 1
        thisNumerator < otherNumerator -> -1
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

This will resolve the compile error without you needing to override the rangeTo() function with custom logic.

Comment: Use can simplify this: 

    `override fun compareTo(other: Rational): Int {
        val thisNumerator = numerator * other.denominator
        val otherNumerator = other.numerator * denominator
        return thisNumerator.compareTo(otherNumerator)
    }
`